# SwiftUI Using NavigationStack with NavigationSplitView not working

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios16

I am updating my project to iOS 16 `NavigationSplitView` & `NavigationStack` from using `NavigationView` with a `Sidebar`.

When changing the selection via the sidebar list, the detail view updates accordingly.

However when using a NavigationLink from the HomeView, if the user then changes the sidebar selection, the view does not update and the selected view is then at the root of the navigation stack, forcing the user to go back by tapping the bar button on the navigation bar.

I followed the following guides

1. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types
2. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/food_truck_building_a_swiftui_multiplatform_app

The following code I expected the remove the last view from the NavigationStack so the selected view is shown.

```
.onChange(of: selection) { _ in
 path.removeLast(path.count)
}
```

**Full code**

```
import SwiftUI

enum Panel: Hashable {
    case home
    case notifications
    case Messages
    case profile
    case account
}

struct AppSidebarNavigation: View {
    
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    @State private var selection: Panel?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            sidebar
            .navigationSplitViewColumnWidth(250)
            .onChange(of: selection) { _ in
                path.removeLast(path.count)
            }
        } detail: {
            // Main View
                switch selection ?? .home {

                case .home:
                    NavigationStack(path: $path) {
                      HomeView()
                    }
                    
                case .notifications:
                    NotificationsView()

                case .Messages:
                    NavigationStack(path: $path) {
                      MessagesView()
                    }

                case .profile:
                    NavigationStack(path: $path) {
                        ProfileView()
                    }

                    
                case .account:
                    NavigationStack(path: $path) {
                    AccountView()
                    }
                }

            
        }
        .onChange(of: selection) { _ in
            path.removeLast(path.count)
        }

    }
}

extension AppSidebarNavigation {
    
    var sidebar: some View {
            List( selection: $selection) {
                
                NavigationLink(value: Panel.home) {
                    Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
                }
                
                NavigationLink(value: Panel.notifications) {
                    Label("Notifications", systemImage:"bell")
                }
                
                NavigationLink(value: Panel.Messages) {
                    Label("Messages", systemImage: "arrow.right.arrow.left")
                }
                
                NavigationLink(value: Panel.profile) {
                    Label("Profile", systemImage: "wallet.pass")
                }
            }
    }
}
```